# MIME type of SQL Server Database BACKUP file

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to find an answer to this. Does anybody know this? I want to enable the download of .bak file and for that I need to know the mime type so that i configure the same in the IIS for .bak file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not everything has a custom mime type.  For generic binary files use `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Right, I was using that mime type. But In the extenion text box in IIS, I was using *.bak. It should be .bak (no asterick). Thanks.

Comment: Awesome find.  I figured IIS would just 'assign' random file types to some default MIME type.  Used this solution to allow downloads of SQL Server .bak files that had to be made available for download!

Answer (score 6):

Just use "application/octet-stream".  It likely doesn't have anything more specific than that.